# Separate Items in ComboBox

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I currently have the below code. I am getting results with my combo box displaying the names, however the names are all displayed in one box next to each other, not as separate items.

```
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadXML);

var xmlData:XML = new XML();

function loadXML(event:Event):void {

    xmlData = new XML(event.target.data);

    for each(var categoryTitle:String in xmlData.categories) {
        cb1.addItem( {label:xmlData.categories.category.attribute("name")} );
    }

}

xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("_scripts/clipart.xml"));
```

This is my XML file layout:

```
<site>
    <categories>
        <category name="Superheroes">
            <captain_america>
                <name>Captain America</name>
                <link>_assets/clipart/captain_america.png</link>
                <thumbnail>_assets/clipart/thumbnail/captain_america.png</thumbnail>
            </captain_america>
            <batman>
                <name>Batman</name>
                <link>_assets/clipart/batman.png</link>
                <thumbnail>_assets/clipart/thumbnail/batman.png</thumbnail>
            </batman>
            <the_flash>
                <name>The Flash</name>
                <link>_assets/clipart/the_flash.png</link>
                <thumbnail>_assets/clipart/thumbnail/the_flash.png</thumbnail>
            </the_flash>
        </category>
        <category name="Movies">
            <star_wars></star_wars>
            <star_wars1></star_wars1>
            <star_wars2></star_wars2>
        </category>
        <category name="Christmas">
        </category>
        <category name="Halloween">
        </category>
    </categories>
</site>
```

I am aiming to display each  as an individual item, as I am then going to have a TileList display the images in that selected category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```
for each(var catTitle:XML in xmlData.categories.category) {
    cb1.addItem( {label:catTitle.attribute("name")} );
}
```

Comment: How would I do the same thing to a TileList but add each item in the category to the TileList?

Comment: if I understood correctly : `for each(var catTitle:XML in xmlData.children().category) {  
 tl1.addItem( {label:catTitle.attribute("name")} );
 for each(var itm:XML in catTitle.children()) {
  if (itm.name.toString().length >=1) {
   tl1.addItem({label: itm.name, source: itm.thumbnail});      
  }     
 }
}`

Comment: I have tried that, however it adds both the categories and the names and the items, and if I change the category, it just adds on again, not replace?

Comment: @Jess `//create dataprovider below this line: var xmlData:XML = new XML();
  var dp:DataProvider = new DataProvider(); 
  tl1.dataProvider = dp;
  //in cb1 CHANGE func add this:
  tl1.dataProvider.removeAll();
  for each(var val:XML in xmlData.children().category) { 
   if (val.attribute("name") == cb1.selectedItem.label) {
    for each(var itm:XML in val.children()) {
      dp.addItem({label:itm.name, source:itm.thumbnail});
    }
   }     
  }` You can also read this:[TileList](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/TileList.html)